# Spring MVC - Force a controller to produce MappingJacksonJsonView(s)

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Here we have a basic webapp using JSP which needs to provide a few JSON based REST service URLs.

These urls will all reside under `/services` and be generated by a `MyRestServicesController`.

The examples I see for settings up JSON based views all use `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`. But it seems like overkill to me as this resolver seems meant for situations where the same URL might produce different output.

I just want my one `RestServicesController` to always produce `MappingJacksonJsonView(s)`.

Is there a cleaner, more straight forward way to simply direct the controller to do this?

Comment: Do you specifically want `MappingJacksonJsonView`, or do you just want JSON to be output?

Comment: JSON output is the ultimate goal, using the standard spring components seems like a best practice. Johan hit it on the head.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a cleaner, more straight forward way to simply direct the controller to do this?

Yes there is. You can have a look at this sample I posted in [Spring forums](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=82146). In short the way I prefer to do it is through the following.

ApplicationContext:

```
<!-- json view, capable of converting any POJO to json format -->
<bean id="jsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"/>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/service")
public ModelAndView getResultAsJson() {
    Object jsonObj = // the java object which we want to convert to json
    return new ModelAndView("jsonView", "result", jsonObj);
}
```

**EDIT 2013:** In these modern days, @skaffman's approach would be a nice alternative.

Comment: Oh yeh, that makes total sense, and is very simple. Exactly what I was hoping for, and super fast response. A million thanks. I must have read about the BeanName resolver 5 times and it never clicked to use it, I think my head was still stuck in template-land.

Answer (score 9):

If all you need to do is output JSON, then the view layer itself is redundant. You can [use the `@ResponseBody` annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody) to instruct Spring to serialize your model directly, using Jackson. It requires less configuration than the `MappingJacksonJsonView` approach, and the code is less cluttered.

Comment: +1 this works for me. Do you know how I could change the content-type?

Comment: There is one drawback to @ResponseBody, after the controller returns, the view is immediately rendered, which closes the HttpResponse so headers cannot be added (such as through an Interceptor's postHandle method).  Using a ContentNegotiatedViewResolver does not have this problem.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you are using [mvc:annotation-driven](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-annotation-driven) and Jackson is on the classpath then all you should need to do is use @ResponseBody on on your methods and the return type will be converted to JSON per Spring's standard [HTTP Message Conversion](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-message-conversion) functionality.

Also check out this video at around 37:00: [Mastering Spring MVC](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Mastering-Spring-MVC-3).